# Solving the the Integral: $\int\frac{\ln(x+3)}{(x+3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}dx$

Tags: integration, substitution

I am attempting to solve the following integral:

$$\int\frac{\ln(x+3)}{(x+3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}dx$$

I have tried the following but I am not sure if it is correct:

$u = x+3$

$\frac{du}{dx} = 1 \Rightarrow du = dx$

Therefore:

$$\int\frac{\ln(x+3)}{(x+3)^{\large\frac{1}{3}}}dx = \int\frac{\ln(u)}{u^{\large\frac{1}{3}}}du$$

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Let $u=\ln(x+3)$ in integration by parts.

Comment: So then $dv$ would be $\frac{1}{(x+3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$?

Comment: Yes (times $dx$.)

Answer (score 1):

setting $$u^{1/3}=t$$ then we have $$u=t^3$$ and $$du=3t^2dt$$ and we have
$$\int\frac{\ln(t^3)}{t}3t^2dt$$
the result is given by $$3/2\,\ln  \left( x+3 \right)  \left( x+3 \right) ^{2/3}-9/4\, \left( x
+3 \right) ^{2/3}
$$

Comment: How did you end up with $t=u^3$ from $u^\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: this was a typo, sorry for that!

Comment: And the final integra, did you solve it through integration by parts?

Comment: yes i did solve it by parts

Answer (score 0):

A single substitution followed by integration by parts will work:  let $$v = (x+3)^{2/3}, \quad dv = \frac{2}{3}(x+3)^{-1/3} \, dx.$$  Then $x+3 = v^{3/2}$ and we obtain $$\int \frac{\log (x+3)}{(x+3)^{1/3}} \, dx = \int \frac{3}{2} \log v^{3/2} \, dv = \frac{9}{4} \int \log v \, dv.$$  This last integral is easily computed by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$I(a)
=\int \ln(t)t^a dt
$.

Based on the other answers,
I'll try to find
a substitution
$t = x^b$
that will make the integral
easy to evaluate.

If
$t = x^b$,
then
$dt = bx^{b-1}dx
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
I(a)
&=\int \ln(x^b)(x^b)^a bx^{b-1}dx\\
&=b^2\int \ln(x)x^{ab+b-1}dx\\
\end{array}
$

If we choose $b$ so that
$ab+b-1 = 0$,
then
$I(a)
=b^2\int \ln(x) dx
=b^2(x \ln x - x)
$.
This requires
$b = \frac1{a+1}
$
which can be done
except when $a = -1$.

When $a = -1$,
$I(a)
=\int \dfrac{\ln t dt}{t}
=\dfrac{\ln^2(t)}{2}
$.

Therefore,
except when $a = -1$,
since
$x
= t^{1/b}
= t^{a+1}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
I(a)
&=b^2(x \ln x - x)\\
&=\dfrac1{(a+1)^2}(t^{a+1} \ln t^{a+1} - t^{a+1})\\
&=\dfrac{t^{a+1}}{(a+1)^2}((a+1) \ln t - 1)\\
&=\dfrac{t^{a+1}\ln t}{a+1}-\dfrac{t^{a+1}}{(a+1)^2}\\
\text{Check:}\\
I'(a)
&=\dfrac1{(a+1)^2}\left(t^{a+1}\dfrac{a+1}{t}+(a+1)t^a((a+1) \ln t - 1)\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{(a+1)^2}\left((a+1)t^{a}+(a+1)^2t^a \ln t - (a+1)t^a\right)\\
&=t^a \ln t\\
\end{array}
$

When $a = -\frac13$,
$I(-\frac13)
=\dfrac{t^{a+1}\ln t}{a+1}-\dfrac{t^{a+1}}{(a+1)^2}
=\dfrac{t^{2/3}\ln t}{2/3}-\dfrac{t^{2/3}}{(2/3)^2}
=\dfrac{3t^{2/3}\ln t}{2}-\dfrac{9t^{2/3}}{4}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: $$\dfrac{d}{d\alpha} t^\alpha = t^\alpha \log(t)$$

So if $$J(\alpha) = \int (x+3)^\alpha \; dx = \frac{(x+3)^{\alpha + 1}}{\alpha + 1} + C(\alpha) $$
your integral is
   $$ J'(-1/3) = \frac{3}{2} (x+3)^{2/3} \ln(x+3) - \frac{9}{4} (x+3)^{2/3} + C$$